# autoplay a wav file on html code

Tags: html, audio, web, wav

I want autoplay a wav file on html code. I find this options on internet:

Don´t work on any browser, but is reported that working:

```
<object type="audio/x-wav" data="http://www.hydrotoys.com/wavs/Beavis_cornholio.wav" width="320" height="260">
<param name="autostart" value="true" />
<param name="controller" value="true" />
<param name="src" value="http://www.hydrotoys.com/wavs/Beavis_cornholio.wav">
</object>
```

work on chrome, IE if Windows Media Player installed, for firefox need manual install for wmp player

```
<embed src="http://www.hydrotoys.com/wavs/Beavis_cornholio.wav" hidden="false" autostart="true" loop="false">
```

html5 solution,work on chrome, I get this solution on mozilla site, but don´t work on IE.

```
<audio src="http://www.hydrotoys.com/wavs/Beavis_cornholio.wav" type="audio/x-wav" controls autoplay="autoplay">
<p>Your browser does not support the audio element </p>
<source src="http://www.hydrotoys.com/wavs/Beavis_cornholio.wav"/> 
</audio>
```

I use a fixed wav on this examples, but I use this code is used for generate my audion on my Servlet

```
            response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            response.setContentType("audio/x-wav");
            response.setContentLength(byteAudio.length);
```

Any help?

Comment: Why the hell are you uploading uncompressed audio data? Use an audio like OGG or MP3 to have much smaller filesizes…

Comment: When you tell us that something doesn't work, we can only deduce that it doesn't work in the behavior expected by you. But it would be more helpful if you told us what behavior do you expect and how is it not working. Is there an error? Or the wav is just not auto-played? What has lead you to the conclusion that these don't work?

Answer (score 5):

Autoplay of wav audio using html5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

 <audio controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
   <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
   <source src="horse.wav" type="audio/mpeg">
   Your browser does not support the audio element.
 </audio>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey Ricardo at present IE supports only mp3 and AAC codecs only check out this link if you have any doubts http://html5doctor.com/html5-audio-the-state-of-play/